# Cost vs quality and performance of H-bridge

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, schottky

I'm working on a project where low cost and small BOM is just as important as optimal functionality. The goal is to drive a cheap DC motor (aka '[yellow motor](https://www.google.com/search?q=dc%20yellow%20motor)'), in two directions, optionally with PWM.

We drive both a microcontroller and this motor from a regulated 3.3V source, which is able to provide more than enough current. The MCU (obviously) controls the motor direction. The motor consumes ±60mA when free running, which I think is pretty close to what it will be doing in the actual product (light load).

If I'd take the 'safe' route, I'd use the [TI DRV8837 H-bridge IC](http://www.ti.com/product/DRV8837) and get a really small BOM and tiny footprint and be done with it. The unit price on a 3K reel for this on Digi-Key is €0,33. This is about 7% of the total product cost (± €5,-).

So IMO there is a case to look into a basic H-bridge made from transistors. For a BJT solution, I'd need the following:

- 2x NPN
- 2x PNP
- 4x back EMF Schottky diode
- 4x base R

When I choose the cheapest parts on Digi-Key for 3K reels, I get SOT-23 3904/6 transistors, some SOD-123, MINIMELF or SOT-23 Schottky diodes and a bag full of 0402 1K resistors, which would add up to only €0,16. That's less than half the price. Using GP 4148 type diodes would save me another 2 cents.

Using 2 P/N MOSFETs pairs, I could drop the base resistors, altough when I search for the optimal solution, I would ideally need gate resistors AND pull-downs. Also, there many questions on this board regarding the need for back-EMF Schottkies in parallel with the MOSFETs, when there are body-diodes in the MOSFET, too. My question is, would the body-diode inside the MOSFETs be good enough for this particular situation? Let's assume not and look for the cheapest parts again:

- 2x 2N7002    2 * €0,024
- 2x BSS84     2 * €0,038
- 4x Schottky  2 * €0,022

This adds up to €0,17 even with some resistors thrown in. So I guess using MOSFETs is just about as economically attractive as using BJTs. But again, dropping the back-EMF diodes would save a lot.

Say we would drop the (optional) requirement to PWM the drive signals, then the amount of switching would be extremely low. How much an impact would back-EMF have considering the circumstances?

-- update

Using a pair of dual Schottky common anode/cathode diodes in SOT-23-3, I can shave another 4 cents off, but adds another unique part to the BOM.

Comment: Is your question « what is the cheapest » or « what is the effect of back-emf »? Please edit your question appropriately. Also, is there a labour overhead for numbers of components?

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike I tried to rephrase the topic. Also good point on the labour overhead. The DRV8837 option as 2 unique parts, whereas a transistor solution has 4 or 5. I was checking with the assembly partner and they charge about $38 per unique part at qty. 3000. This is about 1.3 cents per part per unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at small/cheap NMOS/PMOS FETs, for example: [AO3400](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/ao3400.pdf) / [AO3401](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3401.pdf)

These can handle a very large Id (more than 4 A) which is overkill for your application **but** means that the current that the Body diodes can handle is also increased (compared to low current MOSFETs). The body diodes in the AO340x can handle 2 A so in my view they can take over the task of the back EMF diodes easily.

*I would ideally need gate resistors AND pull-downs.*

That depends entirely on how your H-bridge controls the MOSFETs. If you're controlling the MOSFETs directly from a microController then you only need a high value resistor between gate and source of the MOSFETs. That is needed to keep the MOSFETs **off** when the microController initializes and its outputs are high impedance / undefined.

Comment: Thanks. But these cost € 0,077 each, which runs pretty close to the DRV8837 option, esp. with more expensive assembly.

Comment: Those AO340x are just an **example**. I have **no doubt** that there are cheaper but similar MOSFETs for sale. Just search for MOSFETs with Id_max > 1 A. There are **many** types having very different prices. I do not understand how assembly is more expensive as these MOSFETs come in very standard SMD packages.

Comment: Ok if I search digikey for 1A+ MOSFETs, I get some 4 cent parts, which is pretty good indeed. But when I look at the maximum body diode current of the 2N7002 that I selected earlier, It also has a maximum body diode If of 2A. What is the difference?

Comment: Assembly is more expensive because they count the number of unique parts on your BOM.

Comment: *It also has a maximum body diode If of 2A.* All I see in: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NDS7002A-D.PDF is a maximum **pulsed** current of 0.8 A. I am not saying that 0.8 A or 2 A is not enough. It probably is enough. **You** will have to do the calculations summing up all the costs. I just suggest **a possible** solution, then you use that to make a cheap as possible solution using that idea. Only then can you fairly compare it to the other solutions. So calculate the **total cost**, include assembly and stop saying "it has more components so assembly is more expensive".

Comment: I understand and I really value your feedback, sorry if I didn't really get that accross.  If I use the cheap 2 cents mosfets, i may have to use 4 identical schottkies of 2 cents each and each unique components costs me 1 cent in assembly, it adds up to  4*2 + 4*2 + 3 = 19 cents. if i use your suggestion and  use 4 cents 1A+ mosfets and no schottkies, it adds up to 4*4 + 2 = 18 cents. So in the end it will come down to finding a good deal and working out the exact details, because the example given is of course not fine-grained enough..

Comment: as shown in my other question (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/417082/freewheel-diodes-and-shoot-through-prevention-required-on-this-low-voltage-h-bri) there's another case for using 1A MOSFETs. The yellow motor requires a peak current of almost 800mA to start spinning. I have now built a version of the H-bridge with the cheapest MOSFETs I could find (2N7002+BSS84), but it fails to get the motor spinning.